# Is it ok to use the following array without initializing it?

Tags: c++

I am learning cpp on my own through a book named Programming with Cpp by John R. Hubbard, Phd. The example below is from the same source.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void read(int [], int&);
void print( int [], int);
long sum (int [], int);
const int MAXSIZE=100;

int main(){
    int a[MAXSIZE]={0}, size;
    read (a,size);
    cout << "The array has " <<size <<" elements: ";
    print (a,size);
}

void read(int a[], int& n){
    cout <<"Enter integers. Terminate with 0: \n";
    n=0;
    do{
        cout << "a ["<<n<<"]: ";
        cin >> a[n];
    }
    while (a[n++] !=0 && n<MAXSIZE);
    --n; //don't count the 0
}
void print (int a[], int n){
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout <<a[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;

}
```

Based on the above code, I need to know:

1) Why is the `array[MAXSIZE]` made equal to `0` in the `main()` function? Is it ok to use it without initializing it?

2) What is the role of `n=0` in the `read()` function?

Comment: 1) `={0}` does initialize it. All its values are set to 0..... 2) because arrays indices start at 0,

Comment: @ ChrisMM But why are all its elements set to 0?

Comment: `={0}` is a bit misleading though. It could have been just `{}`. The first element is set to `0`, the other elements are default initialized (to `0`). Try `={1}` to see the diff. Only the first becomes `1`.

Comment: They don't need to be; run the code without `={0}`, and it will still work.

Comment: As @ChrisMM says, in this case, you don't _read_ from `a` while it's uninitialized, so it would be ok to leave it uninitialized.

Comment: Also, obligatory: This is rather horrible example in many ways. If this is from the book, the book is probably quite old? Modern C++ looks quite different, keep that in mind while learning some of the basics from this book... This looks very C-like style, from 20+ years ago...

Comment: @ChrisMM  without the `={0}` the code will cause undefined behaviour by printing uninitialized values, in the case of the user not typing valid integers

Comment: @M.M Indeed. The read loop is not taking care of errors in the input properly.

Comment: @M.M Could you please give an example of  invalid integers?

Comment: @M.M. I'm assuming for such a simple example that valid input is expected.

Comment: @ChrisMM the user not following expectations is a common source of bugs

Comment: @developer `abc` would not be a valid integer

Comment: @M.M, Agreed, but often textbooks deal with verifying input a few chapters in, not immediately.

Comment: Dont use using namespace std;

Comment: @M.M But when testing it with invalid integer without {0} it gives the same result as when it is equaled to {0}: the program aborts.

Comment: It looks like C with cin and cout

Comment: @developer there's no abort situations in your program , you are mistaken about the program aborting.

Comment: @M.M I mean the read() function stops receiving input. It does so, on entering either 0 or a letter, for instance.

Comment: Try typing some digits without pressing enter, and then press the end-of-file keystroke for your system 2 or 3 times   (probably ctrl-Z for windows or ctrl-D for other operating systems)

Comment: Actually I am compiling the code in a mac in xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Why is the array[MAXSIZE] made equal to 0 in the main() function? Is it ok to use it without initializing it?

Only the first element is set to `0`.The others are *default initialized* to `0`. In this case is would be ok to use it without initializing it, that is, even without the `={0}`, **but only** if valid integers are provided.

> 2) What is the role of n=0 in the read() function?

The variable `n` is used to index through the parameter array `a`. Since C++ uses *zero based indexing* the first element of an array is at position `0`, and that's why `n` is set to `0` initially.

Comment: "_In this case is ok to use it without initializing it._" But.. It is initialized by `={0}`..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius this code will work even without `={0}`. That's why I said "In this case is ok to use it without initializing it."

Comment: @Javier Thanks for replying. But in my test, it does not matter if I have it equaled to {0} or not. On entering invalid integers, the program quits.

Comment: @developer Pure "luck". If you enter invalid inputs without the initializartion, your program has undefined behaviour because it will be reading uninitialized values (so anything could happen).

Comment: @Ted Thanks, I get it now.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments!

Comment: @developer like Ted said, what you're doing exhibits undefined behavior and this is very annoying and confusing because it basically means that *anything can happen*. That's why proper (and explicit) initialization is important.

Comment: A better way to read and get validation at the same time would be along the lines of `if(cin >> a[n]) { /*got valid input*/ } else { /*did not get valid input*/ }`